# Access S3 bucket without running aws configure with kubernetes

Tags: amazon-s3, kubernetes, aws-cli

I have an S3 bucket with some sql scripts and some backup files using mysqldump.

I also have a .yaml file that deploys a fresh mariadb image.

As I'm not very experienced with kubernetes yet, if I want to restore one of those backup files into the pod, I need to bash into it, run aws cli, insert my credentials, then sync the bucket locally and run mysql < backup.sql

This, obviously, destroys the concept of full automated deployment.

So, the question is... how can I securely make this pod immediately configured to access S3?

Comment: will these scripts be run on every new mrariadb pod or not? or just one-time task? Is the mariadb pod has its own persistantant volume or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should consider mounting S3 bucket inside the pod.

This can be achieved by for example [s3fs-fuse](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse).

There are two nice articled about [Mounting a S3 bucket inside a Kubernetes pod](https://devops-bordeaux.net/blog/mounting-s3-bucket-in-kubernetes-pod/) and [Kubernetes shared storage with S3 backend](https://icicimov.github.io/blog/virtualization/Kubernetes-shared-storage-with-S3-backend/), I do recommend reading both to understand how this works.

You basically have to build your own image from Dockerfile and supply necessary S3 bucket info and [AWS security credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html).

Once you have the storage mounted you will be able to call scripts from it in a following way:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-world
spec:  # specification of the pod’s contents
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - name: hello
    image: debian
    command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
    args: ["command one; command two && command three"]
```

Comment: That's brilliant! I ended up having a very similar approach, without installing s3fs-fuse. Used kubernetes secrets to configure a pre-existing docker image with ubuntu and some apps and ran a kubernetes Job with aws s3 sync command. Much appreciated, Crou.